# C#: Save embedded Image from Outlook MailItem

Tags: c#, image, outlook, save, mailitem

I'm trying to save an embedded image from an Outlook MailItem (HTML-Body), but I don't find in which property the embedded image is stored and how I can save it.

I have tried to get the image from the property .Attachments (I have tried the index 0) but then a Exception is thrown that the Array-index is out of range. That means, that there is no attachment in the E-Mail.

But if the image is not stored in "Attachments" where is the image stored and how can I save it to the filesystem?

Thank you very much in advance for your answers!

Best regards
Matthias

Comment: is the image actually stored in the mailitem object ? it could be a link in the html of the body which is pointing to some server where it is actually stored. Also you could use [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) to browse the outlook objects in outlook and check their properties.

Comment: Yes, the image is stored in the mailitem object. I can see it in the link in the HTML-Text in the HTML-Body. And unfortunatelly I'm not allowed to install OutlookSpy on my PC.

Comment: Attachments collection is 1 based, not 0.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Maybe this was the failure...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by myself.

The problem was, that I was accessing the MailItem by an other thread. I don't know why but from this thread you can't see the attachments. After putting the Mail-reading-part inside

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { ... }));
```

it works fine. Then you can access the inline image with this code...

```
if (mail.Attachments.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= mail.Attachments.Count; i++)
    {
        mail.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(@"C:\Test\" + mail.Attachments[i].FileName);
    }
}
```